# SQL How to insert multiple lines of data that may vary in amount, into a table from one line of data

Tags: sql

I am basically looking to make order-line level data from daily level data. The catch is the amount I need to convert millions of rows. 
I have written a script that uses a while loop inside a while loop to get this right which works file on small data sets, but now I am hitting a wall because of the amount of data that needs to be processed.

My question is how to I achieve this without using while loops.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempDaily
(
    Item                VARCHAR(5)  NOT NULL,
    Region              VARCHAR(5)  NOT NULL,
    Year                INT         NOT NULL,
    Month               INT         NOT NULL,
    Day                 INT         NOT NULL,
    TotalQuantity       DECIMAL(18,2),
    QuantityPerOrder    DECIMAL(18,2),
    PRIMARY KEY (Item,Region,Year,Month,Day)
)
INSERT INTO #TempDaily (Item,Region,Year,Month,Day,TotalQuantity,QuantityPerOrder)
VALUES ('A','B',2020,05,04,6,2)

CREATE TABLE #Results
(
    Item                VARCHAR(5)  NOT NULL,
    Region              VARCHAR(5)  NOT NULL,
    Year                INT         NOT NULL,
    Month               INT         NOT NULL,
    Day                 INT         NOT NULL,
    OrderID             VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Quantity            DECIMAL(18,2),
    PRIMARY KEY (Item,Region,Year,Month,Day,OrderID)
)
```

This should give you a line of data that looks like this:

```
Item    Region  Year    Month   Day   TotalQuantity  QuantityPerOrder
A       B       2020    5       4     6.00           2.00
```

I would like the results to be as follows:

```
Item    Region  Year    Month   Day   OrderID  Quantity
A       B       2020    5       4     1        2.00 
A       B       2020    5       4     2        2.00 
A       B       2020    5       4     3        2.00
```

Please remember that the QuantityPerLine and TotalQuantity field values will vary over millions of rows. No need to worry about the OrderID field I have that covered. :)

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to split every row into multiple rows depending on expected number of orders calculated from TotalQuantity and QuantityPerOrder.

You'll need tally/numbers table for that. I'm using system table that's good for up to 2047 numbers, but you can use your own table or a CTE. It would be something along these lines:

```
select 
  td.*, 
  TotalQuantity/QuantityPerOrder as OrderCount,
  sv.number as OrderNumber
from #TempDaily td
join master.dbo.spt_values  sv 
  on sv.number<=TotalQuantity/QuantityPerOrder
where sv.type='P' and sv.number>0
```

But don't use this solution as it is. Take under consideration what should happen if values are 0 or null, TotalQuantity is not divisible by QuantityPerOrder, values are not integers or are negative.

Comment: Thank you Adam, this has opened a new door for me. I will re build the script using this solution and see if it improves the run time.